# javascript onchange checkboxes still select on cancel

Tags: javascript, checkbox, onchange, confirm

```
<script>
function no_email_confirm() { 
  if (document.getElementsByName("no_email")[0].checked == false) {
    return true;
  } else {
   var box= confirm("Sure?");
    if (box==true)
        return true;
    else
       document.getElementsByName("no_email")[0].checked == false;
  }
}

</script>
```

And here is my HTML for the checkbox:

```
 <input type="checkbox" id="no_email"  name="no_email" onchange="no_email_confirm()"></input>
```

For some reason, this gives me the confirm pop up the first time I check the box, but not for any click after that. Also, even if I click "Cancel" it still checks the check box. I've searched on here and for some reason, no matter what I try, I can't get it to work properly.

It should confirm if they really want to check the box, if they select "Yes" then it checks it, if not, then it doesn't check it. I can get it to work without the name no_email, but I can't change that..

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You haven't looked at your browser's error console, have you? A NodeList (returned by `getElementsByName()`) has no `checked` property. You either need to iterate over the NodeList, or specify an index to determine element you want to test, such a: `document.getElementsByName(no_email)[0].checked == false`

Comment: So this would have to be checked by default?

Comment: @DavidThomas I updated the code above, and now it pop's up every time, but it is still checking the box when selecting cancel. Is this because it is not checked by default?

Comment: `return false` when 'cancel' is clicked, if you don't want it being checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you've got several errors in there, most notably using `==` when you probably meant `=`.  Instead, add an event listener and make sure the assignment works:

```
var box = document.querySelector('#no_email');

box.addEventListener('change', function no_email_confirm() { 
  if (this.checked == false) {
    return true;
  } else {
   var confirmation= confirm("This means that the VENDOR will NOT RECEIVE ANY communication!!!!");
    if (confirmation)
        return true;
    else
       box.checked = false;
  }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/A3VGg/1/

Comment: this works on the jsfiddle, but even just copying and pasting it into the page it goes on it stops it from working. I will have to check it out, something else must be causing it to stay checked. Thanks for the answer!